# Why has GA4 report data dropped compared to the UA statistics for total users and page views?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

Why has the page_views per month dropped when comparing the user metrics of total_users?

Total traffic to the site has significantly dropped from 1.27 million views(UA) per month to 227 thousand page_views(GA4) per month.  GA4 has total_users like UA has total users, but does not match in terms of page views and total users(traffic) to the site. I have setup and event called "page_views" in GA4, which should match page views from UA. Is there something I am missing or needing to add to the event for it to record all page views and total users that visit the site?

Created event for page_views and total users, not resulting in match to universal analytics